# How to consume Kafka's messages on a single consumer?

Tags: apache-kafka

I need to implement a system that when the application starts a thread consumes all the messages generated during the shutdown of the service, it means that in parallel the application must consume the messages starting from the last message read by the thread that is in charge of consuming the old messages.
Is there a solution to this problem on kafka?

I'm not writing the language I'm using because I think it's a kafka feature.

EDIT:
Suppose we start the machine with consumers at 18:00 from 00:00 must take all messages from 00:00 to 18:00 the consumer assigned to read old messages and in parallel the other consumers start reading messages from 18:00 onward

Comment: This is how consumers work by default.  You also have to be mindful about the retention of messages, as if that process doesn't restart after a certain amount of time you might lose time. Kafka can retain data forever but it costs $$$, you need to find out what is the right retention for you.

Comment: Thanks @Augusto for the reply, I haven't written anything yet, but I'm under the impression that two consumers read the same messages, instead I would need to figure out how to implement it so that the one reading the old messages makes them his own and the new consumers start from where the one reading the old ones finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how consumers work by default. You also have to be mindful about the retention of messages, as if that process doesn't restart after a certain amount of time you might lose messages. Kafka can retain data forever but it costs $$$, you need to find out what is the right retention for you.

From your comment, what you describe (multiple consumers consuming the same messages) happens when they have different [consumer group ids](https://www.confluent.io/blog/configuring-apache-kafka-consumer-group-ids/). If you use the same consumer group, messages won't be processed twice during normal operation.

I need to warn you: Kafka is very complex technology, do not use it unless you know properly how consumers and producers work in detail. I would suggest you to pick at bare minimum the [Kafka Definitive Guide](https://www.confluent.io/resources/kafka-the-definitive-guide-v2/) before using it, unless you are ok with all kinds of failure scenarios.

Also, by default kafka guarantees "deliver at least once". If you want to be sure that you process messages exactly once, please read [Exactly-Once Semantics Are Possible: Here’s How Kafka Does It](https://www.confluent.io/blog/exactly-once-semantics-are-possible-heres-how-apache-kafka-does-it/), and know that this also depends on what you do while processing messages. If you touch a database, it might be better to use something on the DB that guarantees uniqueness (a kind of idempotency) so each message is processed once.